# React selector using reselect - createStructuredSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, selector, reselect

I wonder something if you give an idea I will be grateful.

I am using reselect package first time in one of my projects. I create `makeGetVisibleTodos` selector base on the link below then if I link this selector to the component like below using `createStructuredSelector`;

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  visibleTodos: makeGetVisibleTodos()
});
```

Does it work? I mean if I use this component several times, have I got any problems because of sharing the component? In this way, I did not create a function for `mapStateToProps` like `makeMapStateToProps`.

https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances

Thank you

Comment: seems to be [correct](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createstructuredselectorinputselectors-selectorcreator--createselector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as intended because you call `makeGetVisibleTodos` only once, when creating the structured selector. The resulting selector will be shared between all component instances. If this is a problem (because the selector result depends on component props, you need to add a level of indirection as described in the [reselect docs section you linked](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances):

```js
const mapStateToProps = () => createStructuredSelector({
  visibleTodos: makeGetVisibleTodos()
});
```